# Rails no method error associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

First time caller, long time listener. Im having an issue with my Rails associations. My goal is to make an event website where users can create events and attend events. I have created my models Users and Events and associations as such as:

```
class Event
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
  ...
end

class User
  has_many :created_events, :foreign_key => "creator_id", :class_name => "Event", dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

My Event model has only a description and creator_id foreign key, where my user just has a name field. But I am getting a no method error when I try using `@event = current_user.events.build`. `current_user` just uses sessions to return the user id

I cannot for the life of me figure out why Im getting this error.

I have the full project on [this Github repository](https://github.com/dbateman3/private-events).

Comment: Be sure to check out the [style guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers), you should always try to format the code as best as possible.

Comment: If `current_user` is just the user id, then it's a number not an instance of class User, that's why there's no `events` method. Use that id to get the user you want with something like `User.find(current_user)`.

Comment: class `User` `has_many :created_events`, not `has_many :events`. So, try `current_user.created_events.build` instead of `current_user.events.build`.

Comment: @jvillian Your comment should really be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

class `User` `has_many :created_events`, not `has_many :events`. So, try `current_user.created_events.build` instead of `current_user.events.build`.

Comment: adding to this answer, don't forget to save the new event by invoking: `@event.save` after manipulating event attributes (`date/description`), because the `build` method only creates an in-memory instance. `save` will make it persisted in the database.